# Creating a ListBox style Control with "Show X More"

Tags: wpf

I would like to create a type of control that will be able to see a narrowed and expanded list by some button, an expander or just a button, and also display some hidden items

I tried to create a style that would have a `ListBox` of a certain size (let's say it would be enough for 3 items)

And the `Expander` or some `Button` that would be below it would say how many more items there are

And give the option to expand and see everything or reduce and return to see 3 items

What I created here works pretty poorly and doesn't look good.

I would appreciate help on how to improve it or how to do it in a better and more correct way

```
<Style x:Key="CustomListBoxKey" TargetType="{x:Type ListBox}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition/>
                        <RowDefinition/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <ItemsPresenter/>
                    <Expander x:Name="Expander" Grid.Row="1" Header="Show X More" ExpandDirection="Down"/>
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=Expander, Path=IsExpanded}" Value="False">
                        <Setter Property="MaxHeight" Value="80"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=Expander, Path=IsExpanded}" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="MaxHeight" Value="Infinity"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

public List<string> Items { get; set; } = new() { "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I" };

<Grid>
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" Style="{StaticResource CustomListBoxKey}" VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=.}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Assuming this is to be re usable then I'd consider a template on a contentcontrol. I wrote this article quite some time ago so some things mentioned have changed but the principle remains https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/28597.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an improvement to your code, and it will give you what you asked for

```
<local:InvertableBooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="InvertableBooleanToVisibilityConverterKey"/>
<local:MathValueConverter x:Key="MathValueConverterKey"/>

<Style x:Key="CustomListBoxKey" TargetType="{x:Type ListBox}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition/>
                        <RowDefinition/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <ItemsPresenter x:Name="ItemsPresenter"/>
                    <Expander 
                        x:Name="Expander" 
                        Grid.Row="1" 
                        ExpandDirection="Down">
                        <Expander.Header>
                            <StackPanel 
                                Orientation="Horizontal" 
                                Visibility="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Expander}, Path=IsExpanded, Converter={StaticResource InvertableBooleanToVisibilityConverterKey}}">
                                <TextBlock Text="Show "/>
                                <TextBlock 
                                    Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=DataContext.Items.Count, 
                                    Converter={StaticResource MathValueConverterKey},
                                    ConverterParameter=-2}">
                                </TextBlock>
                                <TextBlock Text=" More"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Expander.Header>
                    </Expander>
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=Expander, Path=IsExpanded}" Value="False">
                        <Setter Property="MaxHeight" Value="80"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=Expander, Path=IsExpanded}" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="MaxHeight" Value="Infinity"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

public class MathValueConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        int.TryParse(parameter.ToString(), out var x);
        return (int)value + x;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public class InvertableBooleanToVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value is bool and true ? Visibility.Collapsed : Visibility.Visible;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would like to present a solution using a UserControl. Actually we have a request for two slightly different presentation. As a first step I build a UserControl called DualDisplay. The DualDisplay gets : "Short Display" and "LongDisplay" as parameters.
The DualDisplay UserControl is hosting the Expander:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
        <local:InvertBooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="InvertBooleanToVisibilityConverter"/>
        <Style TargetType="Expander" x:Key="ExpanderHeaders">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsExpanded" Value="true">
                    <Setter Property="Header" Value="Show Less"/>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="IsExpanded" Value="false">
                    <Setter Property="Header" Value="Show More"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>

    </UserControl.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
        <Expander Name="expander" IsExpanded="False"  Style="{StaticResource ExpanderHeaders}">
                
            <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding ElementName=ours,Path=LongContent}"/>
        </Expander>
        <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding ElementName=ours,Path=ShortContent}" 
           Visibility="{Binding Path=IsExpanded,ElementName=expander,Converter={StaticResource ResourceKey=InvertBooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
```

And the using of the DualDisplay will look as following :

```
<local:DualDisplay>
            <local:DualDisplay.ShortContent>
                <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"    VerticalAlignment="Top" MaxHeight="80">
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=.}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ListBox>
         </local:DualDisplay.ShortContent>
            
        <local:DualDisplay.LongContent>
                <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"    VerticalAlignment="Top" MaxHeight="1000">
                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=.}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ListBox>
         </local:DualDisplay.LongContent>
        </local:DualDisplay>
```

When we use this method we can reuse the DualDisplay for different cases and we are free to design the short/long display as we wish.

I attach also the code behind of the DualDisplay:

```
public object ShortContent
        {
            get { return (object)GetValue(ShortContentProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ShortContentProperty, value); }
        }
        public static readonly DependencyProperty ShortContentProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("ShortContent", typeof(object), typeof(DualDisplay),
              new PropertyMetadata(null));

        public object LongContent
        {
            get { return (object)GetValue(LongContentProperty); }
            set { SetValue(LongContentProperty, value); }
        }
        public static readonly DependencyProperty LongContentProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("LongContent", typeof(object), typeof(DualDisplay),
              new PropertyMetadata(null));
```